# Migrating from Glassfish 3.11 or older version to glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am working on an application that is already deployed on glassfish 3.X running java 7, I want to migrate the application to glassfish 4.1 (java8).

what do you recommend ? I have no idea what steps I should go through, except of course change the addresses and ports  and realm (domain.xml) and everything that is configurable on the code and on the server.

I tried and did some research, but I never got to a convincing result.

maybe you have an idea about that.

Comment: You can never know it unless you try.

Comment: It depends also on your app , if its  uses EJB , Web Services , .... in this case it should have some code migration